# Что значит __declspec(dllexport)

Tags: c++

Искал информацию про *__declspec(dllexport)*, правильно ли я понимаю, что этот метод позволяет, где-то из .dll вызвать функцию?

Например, в .dll есть функция `void print()`
которая что-то выводит.

Если я вызову у себя `__declspec(dllexport) void print()` тогда эта функция сработает у меня, и выведет что-то так же у меня?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__declspec(dllexport)` означает, что функция экспортируется из Dll. `__declspec(dllimport)` означает, что функция импортируется из Dll. Когда компилируется Dll, экспортные функции и классы должны быть отмечены как `__declspec(dllexport)`. Когда заголовок (h-file) компилируется в проекте, использующем Dll, те же функции и классы должны быть отмечены как `__declspec(dllimport)`.

Обычно это делается следующим образом. В проекте Dll определяют символ препроцессора, например `MYDLL_EXPORTS`. Функции определяются так:

```
#ifdef MYDLL_EXPORTS
#define MYDLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define MYDLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

MYDLL_API void my_function();
```

При компиляции Dll `my_function` определена как `__declspec(dllexport)`, так как символ `MYDLL_EXPORTS` определен в проекте Dll. В проектах, использующих Dll, та же функция определена как `__declspec(dllimport)`.

Comment: С экспортом я понял, мы используем функцию из dll, а вот с импортом чего-то не совсем понял, то есть у себя в проекте, когда я хочу использовать функцию из dll, я должен указать, что это импорт?

Comment: @Y0MMY, оно само из-за препроцессора укажется в месте определения функции. Другого писать не нужно, кроме макроса в примере

Comment: У себя в проекте, когда вы хотите использовать функцию из dll, вы включаете заголовок с описанием экспортных функций dll. h-file должен быть написан, как показано в моем ответе. В результате вы получаете `__declspec(dllimport)`, как и требуется.